# VSCode ignoring tsconfig.json and compiling single file generating incorrect errors?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I recently updated typescript, angular, and basically every library in my project. Before I did this update the problem didn't exist. From the command line I've ensured that my code builds without errors or warnings. However, when I open the project in Visual Studio Code and make changes to a file it starts highlighting stuff as errors.

It highlights my imports at the top saying `cannot find module 'angular2/core'.` and my `@Components`, `@Output`s and `@Input`s say `Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.` It's also highlighting some of my `Window` properties that I have declared in a `.d.ts` file.

Yet this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "pretty": true
  },
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

It seems that when I change a file VSCode is building the single file I just changed without using my tsconfig. If I build from the command line I get zero errors or warnings. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to run the build inside VSCode then all the errors go away. Here's my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

How can I have VSCode look for errors and warnings using the entire project and not just the one file?

VSCode 0.10.8
typescript 1.8.7
Linux Mint 17.3 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that VSCode comes with it's own instance of typescript and by updating I surpassed the version that's built in.

[I was notified on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3723#issuecomment-192342749) that you can specify which typescript to use by adding this to your User or Workspace settings:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib/"
```

This has fixed my issues.

Comment: Like it's suggested, I'd prefer to not check in stuff in the node_modules folder. So what do you do if you have typescript installed globally? Specifying path to c://[user] is also a bad options since other people on the team gonna have different user names.

Comment: Don't check in your vscode settings file. Each dev should have their own.

Comment: Each developer solves the issue by putting the line in their own Workspace/User settings.